# Unable to send file in XMPP

Tags: ios, sockets, xmpp, xmppframework

I am stuck with file sending feature in XMPP. Although I am able to receive files.
My turn socket connection fails when user accepts the file from spark.

```
- (BOOL)handleServiceDiscoveryRequest:(XMPPIQ*)inIq {

    NSString *from = [inIq toStr];
    NSString *to = [inIq fromStr];
    NSString *uuid = [self.xmppStream generateUUID];

    NSXMLElement *child = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"query" xmlns:@"http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"];

    XMPPIQ *iq = [XMPPIQ iqWithType:@"get" elementID:uuid child:child];
    [iq addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:to];
    [iq addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:from];
    [self.xmppStream sendElement:iq];

    _fileToSend = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"FileTranfserData"];
    _fileRecipient = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"FileRecepient"];
    _sid = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"senderId"];

    [TURNSocket setProxyCandidates:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:KHostName, nil]];
    turnSocket = [[TURNSocket alloc] initWithStream:self.xmppStream toJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:to] sid:_sid];
    [turnSocket startWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    return YES;
}
```

The following error is received in didReceive method

`error code="404" remote server not found`.

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: That means that the server tried to connect to another server, but failed.  Are you specifying the JID of the receiver as a full JID, like username@server/resource?

Comment: Yes, I am using the full id including the resource.

Comment: I am able to receive files from spark but cannot send the same to the spark, when I try to send the file to send the file to spark, image is  shown on spark and when user tries to accept the file from spark , turn socket fails.